# Bookmarks+ list bookmarks crashes Emacs

Tags: emacs, bookmarks

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and GNU Emacs 23.3.1.

I just tried the bookmarks+ library (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) I downloaded the files from that site, e.g. `bookmarks+.el` from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/bookmark%2b.el

I put the files in my `~/emacs` directory, and I put

```lisp
(setq load-path
      (append (list nil "~/emacs")
              load-path))
(require 'bookmark+)
```

in my `~/.emacs` startup file. To debug I have deleted everything else in my `~/.emacs`..

To make it simple, lets say I now start Emacs as follows:

```
bash$ emacs ~/.emacs &
```

Then I add a single bookmark using <kbd>C-x p m</kbd>, and then enter
<kbd>C-x r l</kbd> to bring up the bookmarks buffer, and I get the follwing screen shot:

[image]

Now there are several ways to make Emacs crash:

- I can just wait some seconds
- I can try to change buffer with <kbd>C-x b</kbd>
- I can select the bookmark and then return to the `.emacs` buffer, and then press <kbd>C-x b</kbd> again..

When it crashes the frame is grayed and nothing happens, whereas in the Gnome terminal I get the error message

```
*** glibc detected *** emacs: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x000000000228e1a0 ***
```

Comment: Is this reproducible in 24.3?

Comment: I cannot install Emacs version 24.3 on my machine, I do not have super user access.. Perhaps someone else can test this?

Comment: You can still build Emacs from source if you have `gcc` installed.
No super user required.

Comment: Ok, I will have a look at that..

Comment: @abo-abo I downloaded from here: http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/emacs-24.3.tar.xz and run `./configure` and got error `checking for libXaw... configure: error: No X toolkit could be found. If you are sure you want Emacs compiled without an X toolkit, pass  --with x-toolkit=no
to configure.  Otherwise, install the development libraries for the toolkit that you want to use (e.g. Gtk+) and re-run configure.`

Comment: I guess you can only build the nox version. Unless you can ask your admin to install the needed libraries.
Here's the list if you need:
`apt-get install libxpm-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev libtiff5-dev libncurses5-dev librsvg2-dev libotf-dev libmagickcore-dev libgnutls-dev libgconf2-dev libxaw7-dev libgtk-3-dev`

Comment: @abo-abo Thanks, I try now to install `libxaw7-dev` from Ubuntu Software Center..

Comment: @abo-abo `configure` now succeeded, I could also run `make` and I was able to bring up the editor with `src/emacs -Q`. However `make install` could not be done. I get the error: `/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/share/info': Permission denied
make: *** [install-info] Error 1`

Comment: You probably do not need directory `/usr/local/share/info` just for this test (though you will need it for ordinary use of Emacs).

Comment: You should say `./configure --prefix=~/emacs`. Prefix sets the base directory of the install. It's /usr/local by default, but you can change it to any directory you want. Afterwards, just add this directory to PATH in ~/.bashrc, so that you can launch executables from there.

Comment: Thanks! I made a `make disclean` then `./configure --prefix/home/fcihh/emacs-24.3` (you need an absolute path). Then `make` and then `make install`. I started Emacs24.3 `~/emacs24.3/bin/emacs24.3` and added a bookmark. And switched to the bookmark list buffer and tested it as in my answer above, but no crashes happend.. Seems to work fine :)

Comment: @abo-abo The final installation directory is now 134Mb.. When I run emacs-24.3 with my original `~/.emacs` I get an error `File error: Cannot open load file, tex-site`.. (I have `(require 'tex-site)` in my `~/.emacs` )

Comment: @abo-abo I used the advice here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122845/24422 and now everything seems to work. Thank you very much for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the same problem after trying a different Emacs build (order not too important, and items are not necessarily related -- i.e., try one or more of these things):

1. Remove `nil` from your sexp that updates `load-path`.  And remove `~/.emacs`, unless it is a directory. `load-path` should be a list of directory names.  And it should include the directory where the Bookmark+ files are located.  Typically, you do `(add-to-list 'load-path "/some/directory")` to add a directory to `load-path`.
2. For your testing, unless you have already done so, remove your bookmarks file. IOW start from zero, as you tried to do by emptying your `.emacs`. Start with no bookmarks.
3. What happens if you do the same things (e.g. `C-x r l` followed by `C-x b`) without loading Bookmark+, i.e., using the vanilla Emacs bookmark code?
4. Remove any byte-compiled Bookmark+ files, so you use `*.el` files, not `*.elc`. Then set `debug-on-error` to `t`. (But if Emacs is crashing then you probably won't get a Lisp backtrace.)
5. Try `M-x debug-on-entry switch-to-buffer` (or whatever other function you think the crash might occur in), and then step through the debugger using `d` (or skip through parts you don't care about, using `c`). For the most clarity (detail), load the Lisp source file that defines the function that you pass to `debug-on-entry`. E.g., if it is `switch-to-buffer` then in recent Emacs builds the file would be `window.el`.  Do `C-h f switch-to-buffer` (or whatever function) to see just what file to load. Load the file using `load-file` or `load-library` (with an explicit `.el` suffix), not `require`, so you load the `*.el`.
6. Every Emacs crash indicates an Emacs bug (Emacs should never crash).  If the crash creates a file `emacs_backtrace.txt` in the current directory then use `M-x report-emacs-bug` and include that file in your bug report.
7. If debugging this helps narrow down the cause of the crash, then consider using  `M-x report-emacs-bug`  to report the narrowed-down recipe to reproduce the crash.

Comment: Problem seems to be that the bookmarks files I installed are not compatible with Gnu Emacs version 23.3.1.

Comment: Can you try to narrow down which bookmark(s) are problematic from that bookmarks file? Comment out 1/2 of them, then 3/4, then 7/8, etc. until you locate the problematic one(s).  It is possible that the bookmark file got corrupted.  Or there might be some other problem.  You can mail me the bookmarks file (preferably narrowed down, and you can change any names of locations etc. if you want). I will take a look.  I suspect a corrupted file, perhaps due to improperly persisting some text properties. (See the `bookmark+.el` file header for contact info.)

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean the `~/.emacs.bmk` file but the files I copied from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#toc2 . I deleted the file `~/.emacs.bmk` and then added a single bookmark, but the problem was still there..

Comment: In that case, please follow up with me by mail. AFAIK, [Bookmark+](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus) is compatible with Emacs 23.3.1 (and other 23 minor versions, and Emacs 22 and 24). Try downloading the files again, and then try starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). Send me the simplest recipe you can come up with.  But again, if Emacs itself crashes (really crashes) then we will need to narrow that down and report a minimal recipe for the crash to Emacs Dev as an Emacs bug.

Comment: Put the Bookmark+ files in your `load-path` and then do `(require 'bookmark+)`. You can do the latter using `M-:` or by putting that sexp in `*scratch*` and using `C-x C-e` with point after the sexp. Use `M-: (add-to-list "/path/to/Bookmark+/files/" 'load-path)` to add to your `load-path` (or eval that sexp in `*scratch*`).